# How to implement proper back navigation when switching from Fragment to an Activity(particularly navigation drawer activity)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer activity that has some fragment.When I try to switch back from the fragment to the navigation drawer activity using the phone's back button I am able to switch to the Activity but the customized toolbar which is there in the activity doesn't come up.Can somebody help me with this.
Below is my navigation drawer code which I am using to switch to a fragment:

```
if (id == R.id.nav_terms) {
            TermsConditionsFragment termsConditionsFragment = new TermsConditionsFragment();
            termsConditionsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager1

                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_user_menu,termsConditionsFragment,termsConditionsFragment.getTag())
                    .commit();

        }
```

Comment: Where is the fragment container 'content_user_menu' placed within the xml, is it below the custom toolbar?

Comment: what do you mean the toolbar doesn't come up, it was on the screen before but then disappears when navigating back and closing drawer?

Comment: @Waqas 'content_user_menu' is below the custom toolbar that is defined in 'app_bar_user_menu' file

Comment: @Rainmaker toolbar is disapperaring only when I am using the phone's back button to pop the fragment to get into activity.

Comment: Maybe you have toolbar set as INVISIBLE somewhere, as I believe it's not about the fragment transaction. I'd post xml and maybe your activity code because I don't think it'll be easy to understand without seeing all the code

Comment: @Rainmaker yes you are right the toolbar that belongs to the navigation drawer activity is hidden when a user switches from activity to the fragment .My activity and fragment both have a customised toolbar but this issue doesn't appear(toolbar invisibility) when the user switches from fragment to the activity using the intent.

Comment: try setting your toolbar visibility in onResume of your activity manually and see what happens cause when you use intent your activity starts with onCreate and when navigating back with backstack it doesn't get to onCreate

Comment: @Rainmaker I tried to do so but onResume method is not getting called when popstacking the fragment.